# Nginx how to block certain post request

Tags: nginx, centos

In my nginx access.log have seen some POST request like these, this request is over 20 time in 1 second, this `tunnel.jsp` there is no inside my server, but this ip can through this way(using 80 port) to change something on my server, how can I only block the `tunnel.jsp` using nginx or there are other ways to stop this without close 80 port?

> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Mar/2017:02:26:24 +0800] "POST /v1/bet/attach/tunnel.jsp?cmd=read HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "-"
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Mar/2017:02:26:24 +0800] "POST /v1/bet/attach/tunnel.jsp?cmd=read HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "-"
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Mar/2017:02:26:24 +0800] "POST /v1/bet/attach/tunnel.jsp?cmd=read HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "-"
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Mar/2017:02:26:24 +0800] "POST /v1/bet/attach/tunnel.jsp?cmd=read HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "-"
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Mar/2017:02:26:24 +0800] "POST /v1/bet/attach/tunnel.jsp?cmd=read HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "-"
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Mar/2017:02:26:24 +0800] "POST /v1/bet/attach/tunnel.jsp?cmd=read HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "-"

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning to ban the IP where the request is coming from, you can try `fail2ban`